# Is it possible to layer sounds in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html5-audio

So I was making a program in javscript, and I was wondering if there is a way to 'layer' sounds in javascript, i.e, to make them play simultaneously.

I use the following code to play sound:

```
var snd=new Audio();
snd.src="sound.mp3";
//Code to ensure this and other assets load etc etc
//Playing sound
snd.play();
```

I've noticed if `snd.play()`executes, say, 3 times a second, it will play it once and wait till it stops playing, instead of playing it whenever `snd.play()` is called, even if it means having to play the same sound file simultaneously. How can I solve this?

Comment: might have to create a new Audio object to play the same sound clip

Comment: have you tested this with multiple instances of "new Audio()".. without having used it in the past... This would be my first guess and that by calling .play... it would stop/restart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new `Audio` object each time you want to play the same sound clip (if its already playing).

```
function playSound() {
   var snd = new Audio();
   snd.src = "sound.mp3";
   snd.play();
}
```

Comment: @Mayhem indeed thanks - was editing as you commented